# How (if at all) has intel new 510 line improved MLC memory durability?

Tags: ssd

I've found a great deal of articles and information that explains the benefits of the new controller and how this delivers performance.

I haven't found anything to suggest that the memory being used is somehow better and more durable.

Is it the same memory as in the previous Intel X25-m series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it uses the same intel 34nm flash that the G2 uses. Write amplification may differ, as a different controller is being used, but barring that, durability should be similar. Intel has a pretty good track record as far as reliability goes, return rate is under 1%.

Answer (score 1):

It uses the same 34nm Intel flash that the G2 X25-M uses, rated at 5000 program/erase cycles. Durability also depends on write amplification and wear-leveling efficiency. These may have improved. I do not know.